# ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED

Tags: android, emulation, 32-bit, ubuntu-14.04

I installed the latest version of the ADT Bundle 32 bit on my ubuntu 14.04 32 bit. I created an AVD, but it doesn't launch. When I press the start button it shows this message:

Starting emulator for AVD 'NexusOne'
ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use them
       you will have to do at least one of the following:
       - Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
       - Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment.
       Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be
       aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
       Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.

I tried to fix it by setting export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true to gedit .profile file and to gedit .bashrc file. Nothing changed.

Thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: You might have to log out and log back in for those to take effect.  But it may also be tricky to get environment variables set on something launched from a GUI.  Realistically, if you are running a 32-bit linux you are likely on an older system where the emulator will perform poorly (it does even on a recent system!) so you may be happier doing your testing on a physical device.  Another option would be launching the emulator from the command line.

Comment: I tried to launch the emulator from the command line but it's the same problem.

Comment: Did you add `-force-32bit` on your command line?  What was your exact invocation?

Comment: I opened the terminal and went to eclipse directory. Then I ran this command: ./eclipse -force-32bit. Eclipse was launched as normally. But when I went to start the emulator it was the same problem as I described above.

Comment: That's an argument to the emulator, not to eclipse.  Start the emulator from the command line - eclipse should find it just like it does a device.  But you will do much better with a device than an emulator.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Have you got the any solution about that!!

Comment: @user242918 Have you got the any solution about that?

Comment: I also have the same problem :(

Comment: It is crashing in the command line. I typed "emulator @Nexus7 -force-32bit" and, after a few seconds of the emulator screen showing an animated "Android" (white and gray in black background), I got "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" and the emulator quit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i have one great solution.
you can start it with eclipse or netbeans.
try :

1. In Eclipse, click your Android project folder and then select Run > Run Configurations...
2. In the left panel of the Run Configurations dialog, select your Android project run configuration or create a new configuration.
3. Click the Target tab.

In the Additional Emulator Command Line Options field, enter:

```
-force-32bit
```

Run your Android project using this run configuration.

in netbeans you :
1. wher you choose debuger chose Customize...

2. in Emulator options write
   `-force-32bit`
3. click ok. and run application

Comment: if I am not using eclipse, how would I be able to use just the command line option for -force-32bit?

Comment: I had to explicitly start that vm for the run configuration for this to work.

Comment: what for android studio?

Answer (score 7):

I solve this problem with the following:

export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true

Then I start the emulator from the command line. It works!

Hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: This works for the command line, unfortunately does not when launching AVDs from the AVD Manager. It seems @user242918 wants to launch them from there

Answer (score 5):

I did the following

go to the run configuration >target tab> scroll down to the last> Additional emulator command line options>-force-32bit

Answer (score 1):

solution to this problem is given [here](https://gist.github.com/CreatorB/2ba2ecca9d7246bed450)

1. Open terminal in ubuntu, and then type gedit  .profile
2. paste this text: export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true
3. refresh source i.e. in terminal type  source  .profile

When no effect, finishing that by restart your device (laptop,pc)

Answer (score 1):

For Android Studio:

Run > Edit Configurations > Android > Android Application > app > Emulator tab

Enable the checkbox next to Additional command line options:

Enter -force-32bit

Comment: There is no emulator tab in Android Studio on Ubuntu platform

Answer (score 0):

go to the run configuration >target tab> scroll down to the last> Additional emulator command line options>-force-32bit

Comment: Add more details on this, so that OP/others can get enough understanding on this.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and now I solved,I have Ubuntu 15.10 And my solution was:

1. Open terminal
2. Locate path directory Android-studio at terminal
3. I wrote export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true, keyboard key enter
4. And execute the ./studio.sh locate in folder bin of Android-studio

Answer (score 0):

**ON LINUX MINT**

1. Go to terminal
2. type *gedit .profile*
3. paste the below line at end of the page
4. export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true
5. type *source .profile* in terminal or restart system

**ON UBUNTU**

1. Go to terminal
2. type *gedit .bashrc*
3. paste the below line at end of that file
4. export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true
5. type *source ~/.bashrc* in terminal or restart system

Answer (score -1):

create a shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#   set export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true

export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true
/opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/eclipse/eclipse
```

change the shell script executable and run it to active eclipse
"/opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/eclipse/eclipse" is the path of eclipse