# Android studio 2.1.2 gradle aapt Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to run Android Studio 2.1.2 on 32bit linux Mint 17.3.
Android studio is freshly installed.
When I rebuild a project or create a new one, I get errors like this in the Gradle Console:

```
AAPT err(Facade for 19314581): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/24.0.1/aapt: 2: /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/24.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Aapt is set as executable in build-tools directory.

I have set:

```
export SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT=30
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true
```

Any other idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try running gradle with " --debug --stacktrace " options to get better idea what is going on. 
More info about the error would be nice, or the code itself (github repo?)

Comment: I have the exact problem and @ph4r05 I tried that and got the same log as posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by downgrading my build tools version from `24.0.1` to `23.0.3`.

1. Download older build tool version from http://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r23.0.3-linux.zip
2. Extract the downloaded file and paste it in your SDK build-tools directory( mostly /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools)
3. Now in your app:gradle file change the `buildToolsVersion` to `"23.0.3"`
4. Sync your gradle file and you should be good to go

Hope google fixes its build-tools bug

Comment: Thanks - this fixed it for me, too.  Being new to this, I couldn't find the app:gradle file, so instead moved the original build tools (25.0.1) into a directory called ~/Android/Sdk/build-tools/_not-working.  This produced a warning, but the 25.0.1 build tools weren't used, meaning the build still went ahead.

Comment: I tried to build a project on Windows with build-tools version 25 and it works. But the same version in linux doesn't work. So as mentioned John you must install version 23.0.3 and works. But the step 2 you can do it from sdk manager. You select install build-tools version 23.0.3 package.

Answer (score 3):

It might be the case the newest Android Studio does not run on 32bit only system. 
On [AndroidStudio download page](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) the requirements for Linux are:

> 64-bit distribution capable of running 32-bit applications

There are also other StackOverflow questions regarding this:

- [Android Studio 64-bit ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31680018/android-studio-64-bit-error-32-bit-linux-android-emulator-binaries-are-deprecat)
- [ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494305/error-32-bit-linux-android-emulator-binaries-are-deprecated)

The former one states:

> Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries,but please be aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK
>   release. Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.

So it might be the case the newest version does not support 32bit anymore. 
Please try suggestions mentioned in the related answers (updating kernel/system). For Linux Mint there is mentioned [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494305/error-32-bit-linux-android-emulator-binaries-are-deprecated)]:

1. Go to terminal
2. type gedit .profile
3. paste the below line at end of the page
4. export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true
5. type source .profile in terminal or restart system

But it also might be the case the newest Android Studio version does not support 32bit-only system anymore. In that case try to use an older version.

Comment: i'm on a 32bit ubuntu machine and get a syntax error i can't fix with android studio 2.3.3