# Gradle on Android Studio loading with error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I'm running android studio on Debian distribution(32 bits) and whenever I start android studio I'm facing a problem with gradle,it keeps loading forever and in the gradle window I get a long list of errors which says:

```
***Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
AAPT err(Facade for 22453413): /home/user1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt: 1: /home/user1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
AAPT err(Facade for 7072356): /home/user1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt: 1: /home/user1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
AAPT err(Facade for 31338389): /home/user1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt: 1: /home/user1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

AAPT err(Facade for 17737675): /home/user1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt: 1: /home/user1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

AAPT err(Facade for 11417836): /home/user1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt: 1: /home/user1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
Thread(png-cruncher_5): Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:144)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
***
```

there are pages and pages of this error repeated.
what can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Share your build.gradle files

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663495/android-studio-2-1-2-gradle-aapt-syntax-error-unterminated-quoted-string

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that I start android studio an empty project.

Answer (score 7):

Fixed it by downgrading gradle to 23.0.3.

http://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r23.0.3-linux.zip

Downloaded it and extracted it in `android-sdk/buildtools`
replaced the `buildToolsVersion` to "23.0.3".

And it worked.

Comment: slight variation that worked on my part. I upgraded to 23.0.3 by simply replacing buildToolsVersion in build.gradle (Module: app) to 23.0.3 and then re-opened the project to let Android Studio automagically download and sync project as soon as it complained it needed to.

Comment: That's because you already had 23.0.3 installed @Faulty. I managed to make gradle compile by updating build tools too. +1

Comment: thank you ......Fixed it by downgrading gradle to 23.0.3.

http://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r23.0.3-linux.zip

Downloaded it and extracted it in android-sdk/buildtools replaced the buildToolsVersion to "23.0.3"

Comment: @DejaVu you should mark this correct. If it really helped

Answer (score 7):

I am running Debian Stretch 64 bit attempting to run a React Native Android application. The fix for me is I had to run the following command,

`sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386`

If anyone else stumbles across this thread with the same situation as me I thought it would save them some pain.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and I needed this as well. I have no idea why exactly but ok.