# Android studio 2.3.3 build error with gradle-3.3.3 and android-plugin-2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In android studio-2.3.3

```
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
```

It's a hello world application.

How can I solve this error?

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.shibly.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to look in this :
 [Gradle on Android Studio loading with error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773326/gradle-on-android-studio-loading-with-error)

"I had the same problem. I fixed it by downgrading my build tools version from 24.0.1 to 23.0.3.

Download older build tool version from http://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r23.0.3-linux.zip
, Extract the downloaded file and paste it in your SDK build-tools directory( mostly /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools)
,
Now in your app:gradle file change the buildToolsVersion to "23.0.3"
, Sync your gradle file and you should be good to go
Hope google fixes its build-tools bug"