# Cordova build failed

Tags: android, node.js, linux, cordova, command-line-interface

I have installed Cordova but when I run  `$ cordova build` in the terminal, it shows the following error. Please help me out.

> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 8.645 secs
>   Error: /home/borsha/hello/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   /home/borsha/hello/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/26.0.1/aapt: 1: /home/borsha/hello/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/26.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

**UPDATE**

> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 2.799 secs
>   Error: /home/borsha/hello/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   /home/borsha/hello/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: 3: /home/borsha/hello/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: You should have the target SDK installed in your sdk manager.

Comment: can you explain a little bit, please?

Comment: Change the target SDK in your app to 25 and make sure API 25 is installed in your android SDK.

Comment: @Brat I have tried but it shows error.now i have updated the question.please take a look .

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading API level to `23.0.3`. You can do that using `Android SDK Manager` and `Android Studio` or you can follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39687455/3968623).

Versions newer than `23.0.3` still have bugs.